# Group by object's field and return list of object or object's id for each group

Tags: django

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    booked_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    bought = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I would like to group tickets by booked day to get list of ticket or ticket's id for each day. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 6, 0, 0, ...>), 
        'ticket_list': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }, 
    {
        'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 7, 0, 0, ...>),
        'ticket_list': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    }
]
```

I could group tickets by day this way and count total tickets per day,

```
Ticket.objects.filter(bought=True).annotate(day=TruncDay('booked_at')).values('day').annotate(c=Count('id')).order_by()
```

But I cannot figure out how to group by day and return ticket objects for that day. Could you please help me solve this.

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to achieve this using only QuerySet. You should filter your Tickets by desired day and then aggregate them in python.